# How can I @Autowire multi task to submit to ExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, spring, autowired

I have a `@Scheduled` service

```
@Controller
public class CheckInstanceStatus {

    @Autowired
    private CheckStatusTask checkStatusTask;

    @Autowired
    private InstanceQueue instanceQueue;

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    public void checkInstanceStatus()
    {
        String instName = instanceQueue.poll();
        checkStatusTask.setInstName(instName);
        executor.submit(checkStatusTask);
    }
}
```

In the example, I can only submit one task to the thread pool. I want to get all (or some) of the object in queue, and put them in a task list (`List<CheckStatusTask>`) and submit them all to the thread pool, But I don't know how to `@Autowired` a Task List(`List<CheckStatusTask>`) in spring.

Do I need to Encapsulate a `TaskList` and `@Autowired` it? In `TaskList` there is a `List<CheckStatusTask>` member to store the task list.

Comment: What Version of Spring (Modules) do you have and where you define your TaskExecutor (Configuration) ?

Comment: spring 4.1.7 RELEASE

Comment: And `TaskExecutor` in my case is `ThreadPoolExecutor`, it's defined as a member of `CheckInstanceStatus`, and is initialized in `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to encapsulate the list of tasks into its own class. Spring will automatically populate a list of any generic type that you autowire. See the documentation for [@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).

> It is also possible to provide *all* beans of a particular type from the
>   `ApplicationContext` by adding the annotation to a field or method that
>   expects an array of that type... The same applies for typed
>   collections

In this case:

```
@Autowired
private List<CheckStatusTask> checkStatusTasks;
```

Comment: I have not test yet, but I want to know, after `@Autowired`, what's the size of the list? I didn't have `CheckStatusTask` bean defined in `applicationcontext.xml`. The `CheckStatusTask` object is dynamically generated, can't be predefined in `applicationcontext.xml`. Is this ok for me?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to have your TaskExecutor Bean (Scheduler Bean) in Configuration Class (XML-Config) such as following example.
Then you have to annotate your Configuration Class with `@EnableAsync`.

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    // taskExecutor properties...
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

In XML:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
```

Mark your CheckStatusTask with Annotation `@Component` and `@Scope("prototype")`like example below.
In this class you additionally annotate your logical Method with `@Async`.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class CheckStatusTask {

    // ...    
    @Async
    public void doTask(String instName) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("task: " + instName + "#" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    // ...
}
```

> By default when specifying @Async on a method, the executor that will be used is the one supplied to the annotation-driven element as described above.

To fill your `List<CheckStatusTask>` you instantiate individuell Objects of Type CheckStatusTask and add them:

```
CheckStatusTask cst = new CheckStatusTask();
tasks.add(cst);
// cst.doTask("Task");
```

Finally you only have to invoke each doTask Method by iterating over the List. Maybe you could skip this operation by call directly this function (in your @Scheduled Method) instead of
iterating and filling the List:

```
for (CheckStatusTask statusTask : getTasks()){
    statusTask.doTask("Task");
}
```